# HyperLinkField in SpGridView

Tags: 2010, hyperlink, spgridview

I have a spgridview with dynamic column.

I get a data of a special list and bind to SpGridView.

I have a URL SPFieldType, i want show description in spgridview and set url for navigationurl.  I use this code but both displays (url and description ).

```
 else if (field.Type == SPFieldType.URL)
                                {
                                    HyperLinkField link = new HyperLinkField();
                                    link.HeaderText = field.Title;
                                    link.DataNavigateUrlFields = new string[] { new SPFieldUrlValue(field.InternalName).Url };
                                    link.DataTextField = new SPFieldUrlValue(field.InternalName).Description;
                                    link.SortExpression = field.InternalName;
                                   grid.Columns.Add(link);
                                }
```

Comment: What type of object is being bound to the SPGridView? A DataTable?

Comment: Yes, it is a Datatable of List item